# Deadlock detected in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, deadlock, plpgsql

I am facing a deadlock problem from a PL/pgSQL function in my PostgreSQL database. Please find the SQL statement in the code block (just example):

```
BEGIN
UPDATE accounts SET balance = 0 WHERE acct_name like 'A%';
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE acct_name like '%A';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE NOTICE SQLERRM;
END;
```

I've found that the deadlock occurred during this statement was running. But I'm not sure that there were other statements trying to update this table in the same time (because I didn't find any in my logging system).

So, is it possible that the deadlock occurred within this statement? As far as I know, if we blocked whole statement with `BEGIN`/`END`. There will be the same transaction and should not be locked by itself.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on accounts? Also do you use explicit locking?

Comment: By default, a transaction can observe changes committed by other transactions.  For more information, see [Transaction Isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) from the PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: @strkol Yes I have, but statement in that trigger is not related to this table. For the explicit locking is also yes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is definitely **some other process** competing for the same resource. That is the nature of a deadlock. A function like you display can never deadlock itself. See [comment by @kgrittn below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077441/postgresql-deadlock-detected/10077634#comment12902733_10077634), who is an expert on concurrency in PostgreSQL.

Your version of PostgreSQL is missing. Modern versions raise a **detailed error message**. Both processes that compete for resources are listed in detail with standard logging settings. Check your db logs.

The fact that you catch the error may prevent Postgres from giving you the full details. Remove the **EXCEPTION** block from your PL/pgSQL function, if you don't get the information in the db log and try again.

To alleviate deadlocks, you can do a number of things. If all your clients access resources in a synchronized order, deadlocks cannot occur. The manual provides the basic strategy to solve most cases in the chapter about [deadlocks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS).

---

As for **version 8.3**: consider upgrading to a more recent version. In particular this improvement in version 8.4 should be interesting for you ([quoting the release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-8-4.html)):

> When reporting a deadlock, report the text of all queries involved in
> the deadlock to the server log (Itagaki Takahiro)

Also, version 8.3 will meet its [end of life in February 2013](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You should start to consider upgrading.

A deadlock situation involving `VACUUM` should have been [fixed in 8.3.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-8-3-1.html).

Comment: I have postgres 8.3.6. This statement just use for example. Actually, I use the insert log to another table instead RAISE NOTICE.

Comment: Normally the error message should give you the information you need. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice. I will continuing to find what other processes were trying to do something with this table.

Comment: A transaction will never deadlock with itself, regardless of triggers.  Version 8.3.6 *might* have been early enough in the 8.3 life cycle that some bugs with interactions between foreground processes and background autovacuum processes could deadlock.  It might help to update to 8.3.somethingrecent to eliminate that possibility.  Planning to upgrade to a new major release before 8.3 hits EOL in February would also be wise.  http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: Can we re-produce the case that deadlock happens while updating table at the same time with autovacuum processes running ? or it not always happens but just sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You would not get deadlock problem, if you add *commit*, to release exclusive locks.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE accounts SET balance = 0 WHERE acct_name like 'A%';
COMMIT;  
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE acct_name like '%A';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE NOTICE SQLERRM;
END;
```

Comment: Procedure in plpgsql run in single transaction commit block, So there is no commit within procedures.

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL, begin means that you start batch transaction.

Your first update will lock rows for accounts `WHERE acct_name like 'A%';`
Those rows are exclusively locked after first update.

Second update tries to open up exactly same rows as first update , to update
fail, because first update has NOT yet committed yet.

Thus second update hit deadlock was rollback.

Comment: In PL/pgSQL `BEGIN` is just the start of a code block. Not the same as `BEGIN` / `COMMIT` in plain SQL.